# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, php, http-error-500, ssh, uninstall-module

When running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` i see this error.

```
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Server internal error. See details in report api\/499296787794"}]}}
```

Searching on my error_log_php i see this

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Downloadable\Api\DomainManagerInterface in /home/user/MySite/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/MySite/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Downloa...')
#1 /home/user/MySite/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Downloa...')
#2 /home/user/MySite/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Downloa...', NULL, 'domainManager', 'Magento\\Downloa...')
#3 /home/user/MySite/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\Obje in /home/user/MySite/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

I've seen suggestions for deleting `var` and `generated` folder, but it didn't work.
I'm interested in solving this since I need to install a new module.

What could be the issue, and I could solve this?

---

EDIT

I've also found that it could be a problem related to the leftovers of a badly removed module. If that is the case, how could I check for it? I haven't installed anything recently, so any issue related to this would be hard to track only with memory.

Comment: which extension remove recently ot disable any things from the stores?

Comment: Recently I haven't removed or disabled anything. I can see this was a thing I've discussed with my server provider like 6 months ago. Their response was that deleting the `generated` folder solved the issue, but clearly this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the solution, at least for me.

I've delete my vendor folder and replaced it with a new one from a base magento 2 instance. Now the error isn't showing anymore. So probably the issue was indeed an old module badly uninstalled.

I'll proceed with further testing to make sure everything works fine.